# Remote Debugger 2015 Update 2 on Windows 7 won't install

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-7-x64, remote-debugging

When I tried to install Visual Studio Remote Tools **Update 2** on Windows 7, I got this error:

- `0x800b010a`

The machine is Windows 7 64-bit, SP1

I need to test the product on Windows 7 also, and remote debugging is required. Since we are using VS2015 U2, I must install VS 2015 Remote Tools **U2**

*Note: IMO, this isn't a question suited for other SE sites*

[image]

Comment: are running a Win7 with all updates? Looks like a SHA256 certificate issue

Comment: @magicandre1981 Not with all updates. Just SP1. I am aware it is a certificate issue - a root CA isn't installed in trusted root store. But which CA? Even the log doesn't show which root CA is missing.

Comment: install all updates. the install has a sha1+sha256 signature and you need all updates, so that WIn7 is aware of it. Use the  Convenience rollup update to get most updates and now search for other missing updates: http://superuser.com/a/996072

Comment: does it work after installing all missing Windows updates?

Comment: (I had posted via SO mobile app - I don't know where the comment got lost).  NO. I have installed and worked on Windows 8.1. Work time lines didn't allow me to research more on it.